# Darlington Transistor TIP142 same type but different values

Tags: transistors, measurement, multimeter, testing, darlington

I have a bunch of Darlington NPN Transistors TIP142 that are removed from two separate identical boards. The 1st one have the TO−218 CASE (left side of the image) and the 2nd the TO−247 CASE (right side of the image)

https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP140-D.PDF

[image]
[image]
[image]

With the Diode Test when I measure the Base-Emiter with N-Probe to Base and P-Probe to Emmiter with the TO−247 I get about 1.368V for all of them, but the same measurement for the TO−218 is OL for all of them (Please note that the multimeter with no probes connected is also indicate OL).

The resistance between them is for the TO−247 about 3.56KOhm and for the TO−218  about 15KOhm.

The other measurements seems to be identical.

So I am really confused and I wonder if some of them are faulty.

> Edit: In my opinion since there are two resistors in series between
>   Base and Emitter there should be a voltage drop. In the TO-247 case my
>   multimeters show OL maybe because there is no much current to draw to
>   show any measurements. Note that the resistance in that case is about
>   ~15KOhm instead of the 3.56Kohm of the TO-247. The datasheet referes
>   that the 1st resistor is ~8K but for the 2nd just ~40 ???? what ?

[image: Multimeter with probes not connected indication]

Comment: please take a clear image of TO-247 and upload it in question..

Comment: The resistance measurements seem to indicate that the TO-218 versions have a higher base-emitter voltage -- are you sure you were reading **zero**, or was your meter out of range?  Do you know what the diode voltage measurement range is on your meter?

Comment: Measure the resistances in both directions (polarities) to see the effects of the base-emitter junctions.

Comment: @AnalogKid It does not matter. Its always the same.

Comment: @TimWescott the indication I get is .OL which is the same i get when is not connected (stand by).

Comment: @Electron I uploaded new images

Comment: .OL basically means infinite, not zero.

Comment: @Unimportant I know this, but As I have already mentioned the .OL is the standby indication for my multimeter (not connected to anything)

Comment: @Maverick: ...but in your question you said "Zero (0)"; not "OL". Zero is not infinity! There is a big difference. Now: what do you get: 0 (zero) or OL (infinity)?

Comment: @Curd I mentioned zero (0) cos the multimeter shows OL even when probes are not connected (or zero voltage). Sorry for the confusion. So to your question I get OL

Comment: In my opinion since there are two resistors (8K and 40 Ohms ????? according to datasheet) in serial between Base and Emitter there should be a small voltage drop and the value ~1.4 should be ok. The 3 transistors with the TO-247 case in the right side of the 1st image are all bad.

Comment: @Maverick: then you should edit your question accordingly so other people don't have to read this whole comment thread just to understand your question.

Comment: @Curd I did it !

Comment: There is not enough information to say that your transistors are bad.  You should see two diode drops from base to emitter (about 1.4 volts, but it can vary).  Because we don't know how much diode voltage is too much for your meter, we don't know when it'll show OL instead of a number.  Because of the way a multimeter measures resistance, the resistance measurement you're making doesn't mean much (but it WILL mean more if you measure *in both directions*, because then the diodes may come into play).

Comment: Chances are low that you have a bunch of defective transistors.  Usually when transistors fail they overheat, and all that nice semiconductor material turns into conductive slag.  The transistor "fails short", and the resistance from any lead to any other reads as 0 (**not** "OL").  It's much more likely that the ones you think are bad are just made at a different time and factory, and have higher drops.

Comment: Manually running 10mA or so through the BE junction (using a 9V battery and a 750\$\Omega\$ resistor in series) and measuring the voltage will tell you.  Or verifying just how much voltage makes the meter say "OL", although that requires you have the right parts in your junkbox.

Comment: Base to Emitter has indeed a diode voltage drop as I already said in my question. The other question is should I have a voltage drop from Emitter to Base ?